# OpenOffice: How to prevent text indentation on the very first paragraph?

Tags: openoffice, indentation, typography

My OpenOffice default paragraph style defines an indentation of 1.3em for the first line of every paragraph.

Now, typographically more adequate would be, if the indentation would be 0 for the very first paragraph of a chapter or after a blockquote (or any other non-paragraph breaking the text flow).

Is there any automatic way to tell OO to leave the indentation aside on these paragraphs? With "automatic" I mean, that I don't want to define another style and assign it to every first paragraph around.

**Edit:** For the ones with knowledge in CSS: I want to achieve something like this with as little hassle as possible:

```
p {
  text-indent: 1.3em;
}

h1 + p, h2 + p, h3 + p,
blockquote + p, table + p{
  text-indent: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution with "first paragraph after heading"-style works fine for new documents. 
if you have already written it, you still have to apply the "first paragraph after heading"-style to all your first paragraphs... gonna save it as template now =)

Answer (score 0):

The setting is: Format > Paragraph > Indents and Spacing tab > Indent - First Line.

You can control this throughout the document by using styles. Press <kbd>F11</kbd> and change the "Default" style to have a First Line Indent of 0.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But this applies to *all* paragraphs (F11 and styles), or to just a single one ("Format" > "Paragraph"). The question is: "Can I apply it automatically to *some* paragraphs (being, every first after a heading. In CSS3 terms: `h1 + p`), without giving every single one of them a new style?"

Comment: I would create a "first after heading" style and make all headings use that style for the next paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to solve this is to simply change the indent of the `Text Body` style to zero, and then under the "Organization" tab select `Text Body indent` from the *next style* drop down.  This will modify the behavior of automatic style application so the first paragraph is automatically a `Text Body` and any subsequent paragraph is automatically `Text Body indent`.

I use this so I can simply enter a new paragraph, hit CTRL+<1-4> to select my heading-level, and then press enter and have this behavior be automated.